# Reason for UITextView found to be nil while unwrapping

Tags: ios, swift

I am new to Swift, and trying to make something that swaps out words for other random words. (If you have any further suggestions to make it work better, please! I am all ears.)

I try and call the text in the UITextView object after the ViewController, and everything is fine syntax wise. When I build and hit my button though, I get the following error for that line:

> fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

What am I doing wrong here?

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        maintext.text = "The Dog Chases the Ball"
        self.submit.setTitle("Change It", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    @IBOutlet var maintext: UITextView!

    @IBOutlet var submit: UIButton!
    @IBAction func submitTapped(sender: UIButton) {
        self.submit.setTitle("Again", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        wordSwapper()

    }

}
var maintext: UITextView!
var AllWords : String! = maintext.text!
// Word Replacer Engine
extension Array {
    func randomItem() -> T {
        let index = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(self.count)))
        return self[index]
    }
}

extension String {
    func replace(target: String, withString: String) -> String
    {
        return self.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString(target, withString: withString, options: NSStringCompareOptions.LiteralSearch, range: nil)
    }
}



// Text imported from Text Box

//: Old Text Loaded as an array

class wordSwapper {
    var Dog = ["Pup", "Canine", "Wolf"]
    var Ball = ["Frisbee", "Stick", "Car"]

        init(){
            var WordsArray = AllWords.componentsSeparatedByString(" ")



            //: New Word Library



    AllWords.replace("Dog", withString: Dog.randomItem()).replace("Ball", withString: Ball.randomItem())



    for Dog in WordsArray {
    AllWords.replace("Dog", withString: "Pup")
    }

    for Ball in WordsArray {
    AllWords.replace("Ball", withString: "Frisbee")
    }

    }

}
```

Comment: Is the `maintext` outlet properly connected in the XIB / storyboard?

Comment: Yes! I made sure of that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are overwriting your IBOutlet here:

```
var maintext: UITextView!
```

That's why it is nil in your method wordSwapper().

Comment: Ah! Thank you. What should I do now? I deleted the line and now suddenly it says "maintext" is an unresolved identifier. Why?

Answer (score 0):

I'm still getting the hang of swift and realized I was calling a variable from two separate classes. The maintext class is a variable of the view controller so I had to call the view controller in the new class I was making first.

Comment: Yeah, right. I didn't notice that you closed the class of the Viewcontroller too early. You should write public classes in different Swift files, so you could better follow your code. I also would recommend to structure your code better to prevent such errors!